# Set xml encoding

Tags: java, xml

I am sending xml to a web service and there I am converting input xml to string and now I am having a problem setting its encoding. Here is a code:

```
        Element soapinElement = (Element) streams.getSoapin().getValue().getAny();          
        Node node = (Node) soapinElement;
        Document document = node.getOwnerDocument();
        DOMImplementationLS domImplLS = (DOMImplementationLS) document.getImplementation();         
        LSSerializer serializer = domImplLS.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput output = domImplLS.createLSOutput();
        output.setEncoding("UTF-8");
        Writer stringWriter = new StringWriter();
        output.setCharacterStream(stringWriter);
        serializer.write(document, output);    
        String soapinString = stringWriter.toString();
```

This code makes a String from request xml. The problem is that when the request XML is encoded not in UTF-8 it produces unreadable characters inside xml elements:

```
<some element>РћР’Р” Р’РћР</some element>
```

When I send UTF-8 encoded xml there is no problem. So the question is how to set UTF-8 encoding when converting xml to String.

Default encoding used by JVM is ISO8859-1.

Comment: I am confused. Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Are you asking a question or are you just telling us that you have solved it by setting the encoding to UTF-8? The default character encoding is not always ISO-8859-1; what the default is depends on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setEncoding` method says what the encoding actually **is**, not what you want it to be. The XML library won't convert the characters.

See this question: [Meaning of XML encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743250/meaning-of-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8/27398439#27398439)

If you want to convert the encoding, that is another question.

Answer (score 0):

I would rethink my whole approach if I were you, generally XML should be kept as a tree.

But if you really need a string, try this

```
    final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    try {
        TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer().transform(
                new DOMSource(document),
                new StreamResult(sw)
        );
    } catch (TransformerException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

    // Now you have the XML as a String:
    System.out.println(sw.toString());
```