# Should I be worried about encoding during serialization?

Tags: c#

```
public string Serialize(BackgroundJobInfo info)
{
    var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter(stringBuilder, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
    {
        var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stringWriter);
        ...
```

By default, `StringWriter` will advertise itself as being in `UTF-16`. Usually `XML` is in `UTF-8`.
So I can fix this by subclassing `StringWriter`

```
public class Utf8StringWriter : StringWriter
{
    public override Encoding Encoding
    {
         get { return Encoding.UTF8; }
    }
}
```

But why should I worry about that? What will be if I decide to use  `StringWriter`(like I did) instead of `Utf8StringWriter`? Will I have some bug?

After that I will write this string to `MongoDb`

Comment: Do the answers to this question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743250/meaning-of-xml-version-1-0-encoding-utf-8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StringWriter`'s `Encoding` property actually is not that useful, as the underlying thing it writes to is a `StringBuilder`, which produces a .Net `string`. .Net strings are encoded internally in utf16, but that's an implementation detail you don't have to worry about. `Encoding` is just a property inherited from `TextWriter`, because a `TextWriter` can potentially write to targets where encoding does matter (`Stream`, `byte[]`, ...).

In the end, you will end up with a plain old `string`. The encoding you will use to serialize that string later on is not fixed yet, and if you're using a MongoDb client implementation that takes a string as an argument, it is not even your concern!

---

On a side note, overriding the getter of the `Encoding`property would not change the way encoding would happen inside even if encoding was actually involved in `StringWriter`