# Why XML encoding required?

Tags: xml

I have a basic understanding of XML. My question is why is it necessary to mention the encoding used at the beginning of a XML document and why encoding is required ?

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5165347/1698732

Answer (score 3):

[It is not required](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-EncodingDecl), although usually you may want to include it:

> In the absence of external character encoding information  (such as
>   MIME headers), parsed entities which are stored  in an encoding other
>   than UTF-8 or UTF-16 must begin with  a text declaration (see 4.3.1
>   The Text Declaration) containing  an encoding declaration.

So, for example, when transferring XML via HTTP, XML parser might use the value from `Content-Type` header like this:

```
Content-Type application/xml; charset=UTF-8
```

But once this document is stored locally, it would not contain this information - thus it seems like a good idea to include encoding into the declaration part of XML document.

Comment: Unlike the `VersionInfo`, the `EncodingDecl` in the BNF grammar notation does [NOT look optional](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-TextDecl).

Answer (score 1):

> why is it necessary to mention the encoding used at the beginning of a XML document

It isn't. There are defaults. (UTF-8 and UTF-16, which can be reliably distinguished between programatically)

> and why encoding is required

Computers only understand binary. Encoding is the process of representing letters, numbers, etc in binary so it can be processed by a computer. Different encodings store the characters in different ways.

Comment: This means I need not mention encoding in the <?xml tag ?

Comment: So long as the encoding is UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: @Quentin, is that  true? From the spec: `TextDecl ::= '<?xml' VersionInfo? EncodingDecl S? '?>' - I think EncodingDecl can me ommited only if the whole XML delcaration is being ommited.

Comment: @AmritaS, <?xml is not a tag per se, it's an XML declaration.

Comment: @Quentin Even the version attribute can be omitted ?

Comment: @kamituel — Those question marks mean "zero or one". So you can omit VersionInfo and/or EncodingDecl

Comment: @AmritaS — Defaults to 1.0. You can omit the entire XML declaration.

Comment: @kamituel — Ah, good point. Nothing wrong with omitting the entire declaration though.

Comment: @Quentin When an XML declaration can be omitted than is there a need to use it ? I think the parser would thrown some error if an XML declaration is missing..not sure though...

Comment: @AmritaS - you need to use declaration if you need to specify encoding (which is usually a good practice). Otherwise it can be ommited.