# ByteString encoding detection

Tags: xml, haskell

As an exercise, I want to write an XML parser (I know there are lots of really good libraries out there, but I want to try it myself).  I understand that `ByteString.Lazy` is probably the best option for any xml file sufficiently large because in memory, plain strings are lists of unicode points.  My question is: should I use `Data.Text.Lazy.Encoding.decodeUtf8With` as a pre-processor or simply pass encoding detection straight to the parser?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How to do this is specified [in the XML standard itself](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-guessing), although this is a non-normative appendix (i.e. you're allowed to do it another way).

Reproducing the algorithm here would be redundant, so I suggest just following the link above.

Comment: I am aware of this.  I just wanted to know if I'm gaining very much in efficiency by doing the non-normative detection myself or letting the library do it.

Comment: Well `decodeUtf8With` isn't going to help you if the input is UTF-16, for example. You can use the algorithm in the standard to decide what the input is and then use one of the `decode___With` functions before running your parser over the decoded `Text`. I think having the encoding handled as a separate step is going to lead to a cleaner core parser.

Comment: Thanks.  I suppose looking at the first bytes and grabbing the encoding declaration into a [Char] string won't be too costly.  As for non-unicode encodings, I just hope that Data.Text.ICU does not cause the memory use to grow exponentially.

Answer (score 3):

This is a tricky issue....  The encoding of an XML document is specified in the document itself (in the  processing instruction).  This obviously leads to a chicken and egg problem, described here- [What use is the 'encoding' in the XML header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165347/what-use-is-the-encoding-in-the-xml-header)

So, if you want to do things correctly, you first have to figure out how to read the first line of the document (is it one byte per char or 2 bytes), then read it, then read the rest of the text using the correct encoding.  Luckily, the first line will be chars in the range 32-127, so that makes things a bit simpler.

If it were me, and I was doing this as a learning excercise, I would just restrict the doc to utf8....  (the details here are just plumbing).