# Convert array to encoded string

Tags: c++, c, iconv

I am using libiconv to convert array of char to encoded string.
I am new to the library.
I wonder how I can know what encoded type the given array is encoded in before I call `iconv_open("To-be-encoded","given-encoded-type")`

It's the second parameter that I need to know.

Comment: `iconv_open` needs to know them. You should already know them. You didn't mention what platform you're on, but I would suggest `iconv --list` from a terminal prompt  on Unix with any reasonable iconv support. They are system-dependent. [Example from OS X 10.10.1](http://pastebin.com/HgdrCwS5)

Answer (score 2):

> It's the second parameter that I need to know.

Yes, you indeed need to *know* it. I.e. it is you that needs to tell `iconv` what encoding your array is in. There is no reliable way of detecting what encoding was used to produce a set of bytes - at best you can take a guess based on character frequencies or other such heuristics.

But there is no way to be 100% sure without other information, from metadata or from the file/data format itself. (e.g. HTTP provides headers to indicate encoding, XML [has that capability too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5165347/what-use-is-the-encoding-in-the-xml-header).)

In other words, if you don't know how a stream of bytes you have is encoded, you cannot convert it to anything else. You need to know the starting point.